# opensaml 2.6 to 3.2 SamlSchema and X509Credential

Tags: java, saml-2.0, x509, signature, opensaml

Hi i am currently porting an app to OpenSAML 3.2 and getting Problems with following:

1- SAMLSchemaBuilder has no getSAMLSchema methods:

```
Schema schema = SAMLSchemaBuilder.getSAML11Schema();
parserPoolManager.setSchema(schema)
```

2- The new `org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.SignatureValidator` only accepts `org.opensaml.security.credential.Credential` not `org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Credential`

```
BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
SignatureValidator.validate(signature, publicCredential);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick look on the [JavaDoc](https://build.shibboleth.net/jenkins/job/java-opensaml-nightly/javadoc/org/opensaml/saml/common/xml/SAMLSchemaBuilder.html#SAMLSchemaBuilder(org.opensaml.saml.common.xml.SAMLSchemaBuilder.SAML1Version)), it looks like som difference in the constructor and then call getSAMLSchema instead of getSAML11Schema.

For your last question, try using the [CredentialSupport class](https://build.shibboleth.net/jenkins/job/java-opensaml-nightly/javadoc/org/opensaml/security/credential/CredentialSupport.html#getSimpleCredential(java.security.cert.X509Certificate,%20java.security.PrivateKey)). It has a method for creating a Credential from a X509Certificate. getSimpleCredential